# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_arc_object' from arcpy.mapping.ListLayers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, arcpy

I'm trying to write a script that allows me to list .mxd files in a folder and then list  the layers in each map document, however, I keep getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py",
>   line 326, in RunScript
>       exec codeObject in **main**.**dict**   File "C:\Users\Daimon Nurse\Desktop\DFMPROJECT\Scripts\editmapdocument8.py", line 9, in
>   
>       lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(file)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 181, in fn_
>       return fn(*args, **kw)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 1499, in
>   ListLayers
>       result = mixins.MapDocumentMixin(map_document_or_layer).listLayers(wildcard,
>   data_frame)   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 822,
>   in listLayers
>       layers = self.layers   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 682,
>   in layers
>       for frame in reversed(self.dataFrames):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 694,
>   in dataFrames
>       return map(convertArcObjectToPythonObject, self.pageLayout.dataFrames)   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 678,
>   in pageLayout
>       return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._mxd._arc_object.pageLayout)
>   AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_arc_object'

This is the code I am using :

```
import arcpy
import os

PATH2 = r"C:\Users\Daimon Nurse\Desktop\DFMPROJECT"
arcpy.env.workspace = PATH2
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True

for file in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(file)
    print file
```

Comment: ListLayers says that it requires a MapDocument or Layer object. Could that be the problem? Check out the 2nd reply in this newsgroup [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/geopython/mj4I3kLGwrI)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try converting "file" to a full pathname, then opening the doc with mapping.MapDocument, like this:

```
for file in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    filePath = os.path.join(PATH2,file)
    print filePath
    MapDoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(filePath)
    lyrList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(MapDoc)
    for Lyr in lyrList:
        print Lyr
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to format code in this forum. :(

Comment: That's OK - just select the code block and hit the **`{}`** button if you are using a browser.  It's a bit harder from the mobile clients but the same principle.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to list layers from a string called `file` that happens to be a map (*.mxd) name.

You need to use [arcpy.MapDocument()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000000n000000) to make a map document object from that first.

Answer (score 1):

For `arcpy.mapping.ListLayers` to work, its input must be a map object. Map objects are created with `arcpy.MapDocument()`

Try:

```
for file in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    mxd = arcpy.MapDocument(file) 
    lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
    print file
```

Comment: I made the changes, but now its saying invalid MXD filename